# How to change the appearance and data of push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

here is image of notification,
[image]

I want to see the code written for this.

How I can change/modify the structure of push notification?

At where, I get code for this in my project?

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cant change the appearance and UI of an iOS push notification.

Though you can always change the push notification data by changing the notification payload from the server.

for an iOS push notification, only description text and sound can be modified

Comment: I disagree. You can always create Notification Content extension and set custom content as per requirement.

Comment: can you make the push notification UI as per your reqirement ??

Comment: Yes, absolutely !!

Comment: Google - "iOS push notification custom view" OR check the link I have shared under question comments.

Comment: @Nitish thanks for the link, i was thinking something else. like android notification..